# ATTACH - Is there a price to pay?

Tags: performance, sqlite, database-connection

When two databases are attached is there a hit in performance compared to having a separate connection to each? Also, if I was writing data to one of the attached databases would both databases be locked or just the one being written to?

The reason I ask is it just seems simpler to me to have one connection that I ATTACH / DETACH each database to / from as it becomes needed / redundant rather than opening and closing connections to each of them all the time. My app doesn't have any threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction are atomic over all attached databases; this requires creating a separate [master journal](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#rollback) in addition to all the normal rollback journals of the actual databases.

When having attached databases, table names (and [PRAGMA statements](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)) might require that the database name is added.

For these reason, ATTACH is usually used only when you actually need to access multiple databases in the same query.